# Convert timestamp to Mst format

Tags: dataweave

could you provide below output based on the input 'Timestamp'

```
Input:
[{
  "FLAG": "N",
  "TIMESTAMP": "2022-09-18T16:59:42"
}]

Output:
{
 timestamp: "itemMst_18/Sep/2022 17:14:42:000.dat"
}
```

Comment: What is an MST format?

Comment: It seems that it is a file name format specific to your business rules. You should provide that kind of information upfront. Why the time is different between the input and the output?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the timestamp in the output is a file name that contains the date time from the input timestamp just reformat it and concatenate the prefix and extension name:

```json
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    timestamp: "itemMst_" ++ payload[0].TIMESTAMP as DateTime as String { format: "dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" } ++ ":000.dat"
}
```